# Firebase Query not returning the Value which it matches

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my code is this

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

and the query is like this

```
query =  application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                    .startAt("vikass").endAt("vikass"+"\uf8ff");
                query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

if my database value is vikassharma when i query vikass it returns nothing

Comment: can you show us your database structure?

Comment: user_details{displayName:vikassharma}

Comment: is string.db_user_details matching the name of your child in your database?

Comment: yes i am 200 percent sure about it

Answer (score 1):

If you have this database:

```
rootNode
  user_details
       displayName: vikassharma
```

then you do not need to add `child(getString(R.string.db_user_details))`, you can just do this:

```
query =  application.getMRef().orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                .startAt("vikass").endAt("vikass"+"\uf8ff");
            query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```